# 'str' object has no attribute 'base_dtype' error TensorFlow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am implementing a Wasserstein DCGAN in TensorFlow.
This is my generator model :

```
w1 = tf.get_variable('w1', shape=[random_dim, 1024], dtype=tf.float32,
                             initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
b1 =  b1 = tf.get_variable('b1', shape=[1024], dtype=tf.float32,
                     initializer=tf.constant_initializer(1.0))
flat_conv1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(input , w1) , b1 , name = 'flat_conv1')
act1 = tf.nn.tanh(flat_conv1, name='act1')

dense1 = tf.layers.dense(bias_initializer=tf.ones_initializer(),inputs=act1, units=128*7*7, activation=tf.nn.tanh , kernel_initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
bn1 = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(dense1, is_training=is_train, epsilon=1e-5, decay = 0.9,  updates_collections=None, scope='bn1')
act2 = tf.nn.tanh(bn1, name='act1')

conv1 = tf.reshape(act2, shape=[-1,7,7,128], name='conv1')
up1 = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))

conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(bias_initializer=tf.ones_initializer(),inputs=up1,filters=64,kernel_size=[5, 5],padding="same",activation=tf.nn.tanh , kernel_initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
up2 = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))
conv3 = tf.layers.conv2d(bias_initializer=tf.ones_initializer(),inputs=up2,filters =1,kernel_size=[5, 5],padding= "same",activation=tf.nn.tanh , kernel_initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
```

The error is in the conv2 layer and it says - ''str' object has no attribute 'base_dtype'
I am a newbie to TensorFlow and cannot figure out why is it so.
COMPLETE SOURCE CODE : https://github.com/tanmay-bhatnagar/W-DCGAN
Obtained `train` function from here :https://github.com/llSourcell/Pokemon_GAN/blob/master/pokeGAN.py

Please ask for any further details that are required.

Comment: The `inputs`-parameters to `conv2d()` must be tensor. See C. Park's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work

```
up1 = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv1)
up2 = tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv2)
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Can you please explain what did adding a (conv1) change. I have never seen such a function call in python.

Comment: @TammyBhatnager The first parentheses are for **class(`UpSampling2D`) instantiation**, and the second ones are for calling the **___call__()** method of the instance(It's called **Callable Object** in python). Keras layers (including `UpSampling2D`) have **___call__(input, **)** method which returns wrapper for handle given input.

Comment: Can you please checkout another error that has occured here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48791793/can-not-convert-a-ndarray-into-a-tensor-or-operation-error-in-tensorflow-model. And if it isnt too much to ask please upvote the question I rarely get those on mine. Thank you