# Can not convert a ndarray into a Tensor or Operation error in TensorFlow model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am implementing a Wasserstein DCGAN in TensorFlow. The error occurs when this line is run : `train_image = sess.run(image_batch)`. The handling of this exception throws another exception

```
Fetch argument array([[[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]],

       ...,

       [[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]]], dtype=uint8) has invalid type <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, must be a string or Tensor. (Can not convert a ndarray into a Tensor or Operation.)
```

I am using the MNIST dataset fetched using this command -->

`from keras.datasets import mnist
 (X_train, Y_train), (X_test, Y_test) = mnist.load_data()`

COMPLETE SOURCE CODE : https://github.com/tanmay-bhatnagar/W-DCGAN
Using TensorFlow 1.4.1 and python 3.6 with latest version of all other libraries.
Please ask for any other details that are required.

Comment: what is the purpose of the line `rain_image = sess.run(image_batch)`? You can't pass numpy array into there.

Comment: I actually copied the training loop from here making a few changes but not to the sessions : https://github.com/llSourcell/Pokemon_GAN/blob/master/pokeGAN.py. I do not yet fully understand tensorflow seesions as I used to code in keras so I do not understand the purpose of that session.

Comment: when i change the line to `train_image = image_batch` it throws a ValueError saying `ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (64, 28, 28) for Tensor 'input/real_image:0', which has shape '(?, 28, 28, 1)'`. So the session might be to process the `image_batch`

Comment: Your `process_data` function returns numpy array but pokeGan's one returns tensorflow operation (can be passed into `sess.run()`)

Comment: so how do i convert that into a tensorflow operation ?

Comment: This may work.. Add `tf.reshape(image_batch, [-1,64,64,1])` into `process_data` before return.

Comment: Or you can do `np.reshape()` and directly feed to the `real_image`.

Comment: I did the `tf.reshape(image_batch , [-1 , 64 , 28 , 28]` but this led to an error in this line `_, dLoss = sess.run([trainer_d, d_loss],
                                    feed_dict={random_input: train_noise, real_image: train_image, is_train: True})`. Error says ; `The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. Acceptable feed values include Python scalars, strings, lists, numpy ndarrays, or TensorHandles.

`

Comment: Did you removed `train_image = sess.run(image_batch)` from your code? You should remain it.

Comment: Yes I did. I corrected it but still the ValueError persists saying : ``Cannot feed value of shape (1, 64, 28, 28) for Tensor 'input/real_image:0', which has shape '(?, 28, 28, 1)'. By the way man you caught that error like a programming god.

Comment: Fixed it. `tf.reshape(image_batch, [64,28,28,1])`. I remembered that TensorFlow treats the first value of the four as the batch size

Comment: @ C.Park Thanks a lot !

Comment: you're welcome :D

Answer (score 0):

Before passing `(X_train, Y_train), (X_test, Y_test)`, make sure you are using [`tf.convert_to_tensor()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/convert_to_tensor) to convert them to tensors in your code.