# Creating a submodel using textVectorization and Embedding layers in Keras throws: 'str' object has no attribute 'base_dtype' in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook

I'm making a multi-input Tensorflow NLP model using text and numerical data. To create this, I plan on making two submodels, one for text and the other for numerical data, and then concatenating their outputs into my main model. For the text submodel, I've been following the Keras guides for text vectorization and embeddings (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/word_embeddings#configure_the_dataset_for_performance and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/experimental/preprocessing/TextVectorization) and used TF-IDF weighting, indexing all bigrams. This is the code for the TextVectorization layer:

```
# Instantiate TextVectorization with "tf-idf" output_mode
# (multi-hot with TF-IDF weighting) and ngrams=2 (index all bigrams)
text_vectorizer = preprocessing.TextVectorization(output_mode="tf-idf", ngrams=2)
# Index the bigrams and learn the TF-IDF weights via `adapt()`
text_vectorizer.adapt(df['tweet_punct'].dropna().to_numpy())
print('Size of vocabulary:', len(text_vectorizer.get_vocabulary()))
vocab_size = len(text_vectorizer.get_vocabulary())
```

The error comes when I try to connect my vectorization layer to an embedding layer. This is the following script I've been using:

```
embedding_layer = Embedding(vocab_size, 100)(text_vectorizer)
LSTM_layer_1 = LSTM(128)(embedding_layer)
```

According to the only other question I could find related to this problem: ['str' object has no attribute 'base_dtype' error TensorFlow model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48771136/str-object-has-no-attribute-base-dtype-error-tensorflow-model) the way the layers are added to each other should be right, yet running this gives me `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'base_dtype'` on the first line. Is there an issue with how I'm connecting the two layers? I am sort of new to Tensorflow and have never attempted to make a model this way so I am a little lost on what is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

Your `text_vectorizer` would be your first layer after your input layer. It is used like a normal layer and not like a dictionary.

```
import tensorflow as tf
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string)
x = text_vectorizer(inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs, name="mymodel")
```